# How do I incorporate runestones into my magic system?

Tags: technological-development, balancing-magic-systems

Orgone, also referred to as Mana, is the conduit through which the power of the cosmos flows, focused through a sorcerer's will. Ritual practitioners must draw on this reserve of power in their souls to make a magic spell work. Spells require a constant infusion of Orgone through rituals that are performed inside a transmutation circle, which require a number of ingredients and can last anywhere from 30 minutes to several hours depending on the spell.

This magic system is not too friendly to attack magic: If it takes you an hour to form a thundershock attack, it's pretty useless. However, a recent innovation bypasses this handicap in the form of rune stones. These stones are hand-sized, portable stones infused with a spell on the same process described above. The stone stores the spell for later, long-term use. The spell is also instant, avoiding the drawn-out process of the rituals.

There are two problems I can forsee with this, as the same advantages that make it valuable can also make them dangerous to society at large.:

1. Runestones provide immediate access to a spell, making mages less needed or in demand. This threatens the necessity of mages altogether, which is not what I want.
2. ( You slept with my wife!!? I'm going to pull out a runestone from my backpack and blast you with a  ball you jackass!!!) Individuals can infuse a spell to a stone and walk around with one for immediate usage. This can pose a threat in communities.

How can I place natural limitations on the effectiveness of runestones to incorporate them into my magic system, and yest still make them useful for everyday life?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways that I think you could use. If you have the method of creating a rune-stone be a magical one, basically a spell to store another spell in itself until the storage is released, then:

The first would be that making a rune-stone requires a minimum of 2 sorcerers, one to cast the spell to be stored, and one to cast a spell to store it in the stone. Based on your previous questions, I would imagine that the storage spell fits into your enchantment school, by enchanting the stone to 'store until x action'. A single sorcerer cannot do this as it is two separate spells and rituals.

The second part, is to have the storage spell begin to break down as soon as the ritual is complete, due to the magic source being removed. The speed this occurs at is up to you, but might range from a couple of days for low level spells, a few weeks for a mid level fireball equivalent, and a few months for a high level lightning storm or earthquake spell.

This would lead into my third point, 
As the storage spell breaks down, it begins to affect its surroundings, and any magic near it. Storing to many rune-stones near each other would have disastrous effects, as was seen when the effects of 5 earthquake spells, 100 storms, and 500 fireballs all compounded and left a certain city uninhabitable for over a year.
This makes people have to carefully consider what they need the most, they cant just build up a stockpile as much as they want. One runestone containing an earthquake spell has no noticeable effect. Two, and seismograph instruments in the area might measure a magnitude 1 effect. Three, and you have magnitude 4 earthquakes, and 5 and you have magnitude 8 earthquakes.

With this set up, you can have the storage spell be renewable by having the sorcerer infuse power back into the spell through another ritual of storage, thereby giving necessity for anyone who wants to build a stockpile of stones to keep at least one sorcerer around. 
If you decide that the spell is not renewable, then anyone who wants to build up a stockpile would need to keep a few sorcerers around, constantly making fresh stones, keeping inventory of the age and quality of older stones, and safely disposing of those that are about to expire.

Finally, creating massive stockpiles would be extremely hard, as the stones cannot be stored together, see point 3. At most, a king might have 2-3 High level stones, maybe 15-20 mid level and up to 100 low level stones. These would be spread out between different military forts so as not to interfere with each other.

You could also use the answer given by @cegfault and have normal citizens require a licence to purchase the rune-stones.

Answer (score 6):

> 1. Runestones provide immediate access to a spell, making mages less needed or in demand. This threatens the necessity of mages altogether, which is not what I want.

No problem here. Who *makes* the runestones? It's mages. Who would fix the runestone after it's created? It's mages again. Remove the mages and you don't have access to runestones. No new ones, at least and the old ones would eventually go obsolete. At the most basic case - somebody can drop a runestone and that's one less for *eternity*. If a shipment of runestones sinks with a ship or something, then the total amount of runestones also decreases. So, they will quickly become a very valuable commodity.

Moreover, there is even less of a problem of *somehow* being able to use runestones forever:

> Orgone, also referred to as Mana, is the conduit through which the power of the cosmos flows

You need Orgone.

> Spells require a constant infusion of Orgone

Spells don't work without it.

> [Runestones] are hand-sized, portable stones **infused with a spell on the same process described above**

(emphasis mine)

You need to *charge* the spell in order to use it. The runestones don't change this. So, if you need X amount of Orgone to cast a fireball, the spellstone also needs to be infused with (at least) X amount of Orgone.

> [Orgone is] focused through a sorcerer's will

Normal people cannot use a spell more than `runestone_Orgone_capacity ÷ spell_Orgone_requirement` times. And since mages are the people who can manipulate Orgone, they are a *requirement* for runestones to work in the long term. After a fireball or two, that runestone becomes a fancy paperweight.

The recharging method *might* be just adding more Orgone but perhaps a mage needs to re-cast the entire spell *again*.

In fact, mages are so crucial to the runestones, that they can and *will* control the supply and distribution of runestones. No way around it - only the foolish will continue making and giving away runestones.

1. It's *taxing* for them. Sure a runestone user only needs to wave the stone (or whatever) to activate it and they get the effect but behind that there was a mage that stood in the transmutation circle, used the correct ingredients, channelled Orgone and did that for whatever time the ritual takes. Sounds like it's not something you just do whenever you feel like it. There is a finite amount of runestones a mage can create for a given time, say, 15 runestones a week. And that's if we consider they *only* do this all day every day. But a mage might be busy and can't cast spells on Wednesday. Or a mage might need to cast a *different* spell for personal use. In either case, that's less runestones being created.
2. Mages will quickly realise that if they flood the market with runestones, there would be less demand for their services. If you give out 500 runestones with "Bless crops" to the peasents, that means they won't come to you for extra "Bless crops" castings. But if you give out 50 runestones to get people hooked and then charge premium for casting "Bless crops", you can get a lot more out of the deal. Money, respect, power, influence.

> 2. ( You slept with my wife!!? I'm going to pull out a runestone from my backpack and blast you with a  ball you jackass!!!) Individuals can infuse a spell to a stone and walk around with one for immediate usage. This can pose a threat in communities.

Yes, and many countries allow the same thing to happen. Only it's not runestones but weapons. Anybody can walk around with a knife and stab his wife's lover. Or they can carry a gun and shoot the lover. In the middle ages, they could even carry a crossbow. We've survived.

As a society, we figured out murder is not very desirable, so we've put some protections in place. *In general*, we don't encourage killing people (exceptions like war exist, of course) and murder in particular is very frowned upon. We punish murderers rather harshly - by killing them (depending on location and time period) or otherwise making an example out of them for "don't murder or this will happen to you". Also, somewhat surprisingly, when we *do* approve of killing, there are all sorts of social rituals needed like challenging to a duel, for example. Most of this applies to harm of other kinds, too - there might be more lax rules against just punching somebody in the face for no reason but it's also not something we really want.

So, society has safeguards against murder and harm. Yes, they don't prevent *all* incidents but a person with a runestone who is a threat will likely be a threat even without it. Runestones change very little for communities. In general, at least.

A society with handy magic will likely have other safeguards against somebody using a runestone to harm it.

1. First of all, *restricting* the runestones.

   - Peasants in the middle ages didn't have access to a lot of weapons like swords. It's simply not something they were allowed *and/or* it was prohibitively expensive. The equipment for a single soldier might take up the tax money from an entire village. It's not like the peasants would just go and buy swords in bulk in this situation.
   - In more modern times, guns are regulated. The amount of control varies between countries, true, but every country I know of has *some* rules about guns. Especially about *using them*. Shoot people willy-nilly and you'll quickly find out how much people dislike being shot at. Same idea with runestones - they can be controlled. In fact, runestones are *easier* to control than runs - runestones are very reliant on mages, as described above. Mages have a vested interest in *not* being fireballed in the face. They also have interest in restricting the amount of stones in circulation *anyway* also as described above.
2. The society will demand sufficient reason for runestone possession and usage. Even in our world, somebody owning a gun will at least rise an eyebrow, but (depending on location), this can lead to even more consequences - questions, concerns, ostracism, heightened awareness of the individual, etc. That's *normal guns*. Even societies with less restrictions of those will have *some* reaction when they find out somebody owns a gun. Now imagine somebody owns a *rocket launcher*. Because that's more comparable with a fireball runestone. Your neighbour might be cool that you have firearms but will really not want you to use a rocket launcher around his property. A medieval society will likely be *extremely* pissed that somebody has the means of casually burning down all their homes and that doesn't even need to happen out of *malice*. A jealous husband fireballing a poor guy can lead to several houses catching on fire.
3. Harsh sanctions of using runestones to bring harm to a society. Authorities can get involved but the community can just take matters in their own hands, too. Again I point towards how murderers are treated. Society doesn't like being harmed. This can be a deterrent in itself - "Remember what happened with Bob after he fireballed that guy? You don't want the same happening to you, right". Even if the threat of bringing down the ire of society is not enough and harm *is* done, society's defence mechanism is to destroy and contain all similar threats. One firaball and you might find *all* runestones in the village being rounded up and destroyed. Just in case. It could also be worse - incidents in our own history have resulted with witch-hunts. Sometimes *literal*. And sometimes these cause more harm than the incident that started the mass hysteria. Or sometimes there was no incident yet mass hysteria erupted. Look at the Salem witch trials or the more recent Satanic panic for examples. At any rate, the post-factum reaction of society can also serve to limit the amount of harm runestones would do.

With all that said, I don't really see a problem. If anything, seems quite likely that mages will join in a society of some kind (even if loose, just to discuss ideas) and would probably collectively come up with limitations to runestones. It's literally more inconvenience for them, the more runestones are out there in the world. The mage society might even reduce all of your concerns by their own volition, if they decide to be *really* stingy with runestones. This can be done as benign preventative measure or just greedy motivation - essentially keeping the supply low to extort more for themselves.

Answer (score 5):

## Magic Energy-Battery

What you have as a rune stone is basically a magic energy-battery.  Your cell phone can stay in a passive state for (up to) a few days, depending on the model and battery size.  But if you use your phone, you'll have to recharge it.  Your rune stones can only last so long, and from the second the spell is ingrained on them they begin to lose potency - very slowly, but still.  Furthermore, once it's used it needs to be "re-charged".  That is, the spell needs to be cast again.

So if you want to carry around a thousand spells you're going to need a wheelbarrow.  That's not fun.  People will immediately optimize for what they *think* they might *need* immediately.  There's no reason a man would carry a fireball spell in his backpack unless he already suspected his wife was cheating and planned to kill the guy - sounds like solid evidence of malice aforethought (ie, bumps that up from 2nd-degree murder to 1st-degree murder in the eyes of the law).

Furthermore, as in any society, someone carrying around a literal wheelbarrow or truckload of runestones is a *very, very dangerous site*.  We have legal restrictions and require licenses for the transportation of gunpowder, hazardous materials, explosives, etc.  This would be the same thing in your world.  Just as watching a guy carrying around five guns and a host of grenades would result in many calls to the police, so someone carrying around a ton of runestones would elicit *immediate* safety concerns and would be met with *immediate* government actions.

A fun side note: it would be interesting to see the black market for rune stones in this type of setting.  There's also a lot of political commentaries possible (as some [not all] guns are allowed in America, there's constant debates of "acceptable use" and what regulations are needed/wanted/dangerous - similar overlay with your runestones).

Answer (score 0):

one simple idea would just be to make it so that only well trained sorcerers can use them?

Like, the "unleash" spell needed to be used on the stones to force them to let out their energy requires physical contact with the stone, and a large amount of magical skill to use, even if it is basically instant.